# How do I revert a function after a timer in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to revert this variable back to 0 after 2/3 seconds so i can press it again.

```
 function Spawn() {
     firebase.database().ref('Boolbtn').set({
       Boolbtn: 1
    });
  };
```

Comment: You mean, with a `setTimeout` that calls `Unspawn`? So basically, you create `TriggerField( property, value )` function that you then reference from `Spawn` as `TriggerField('BoolBtn', 1)` and run a `setTimeout( _ => TriggerField('BoolBtn', 0), 666)`

Comment: what did you try to create that functionality?

Comment: setTimeout(Spawn, 666);

Comment: I use this function to change the Boolbtn variable from 0 to 1 so i can use it as a boolean. However i want to change the boolean back to 0 after a specific time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This waits for the db to set the value first and *then* waits 2/3 seconds.

```js
 function Spawn() {
     firebase.database().ref('Boolbtn').set({
       Boolbtn: 1
    }, function() { // set value to zero after it is set in the db
       setTimeout(function() {
       firebase.database().ref('BoolBtn').set({
          Boolbtn: 0
       })
       }, (2/3)*1000) // wait for 2/3 seconds
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use a `setTimeout`:

```js
function toggleButton(on) {
  firebase.database().ref('Boolbtn').set({
    Boolbtn: on ? 1 : 0
  });
};

function Spawn() {
  toggleButton(true);

  setTimeout(() => {
    toggleButton(false);
  }, 1000 * 2 / 3)
}
```

Comment: So, when using this it will revert it back to 0. Is this the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I think it's fairly efficient. If you'd like to not repeat code, you can change your function to take make the function take a variable as an argument

Comment: ```        <button class="btn spawn" onclick="Spawn()">Spawn</button> ```

Comment: The line of code above i use in my html to start the function, also sorry for my clunkyness. New to programming and also this website.

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer so that your existing button code should work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the following way:

```
function updateField(name, value) {
  return firebase.database().ref( name ).set({ [name]: value });
}

function spawn() {
  return updateField( 'BoolBtn', 1 ).then( _ => setTimeout( unspawn, 666 ) );
}

function unspawn() {
  return updateField( 'BoolBtn', 0 );
}

// on click event
spawn();
```